# Assume $r,s \in\mathbb{Q}$. Prove $\frac{r}{s},r-s \in\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: proof-explanation, rational-numbers

I have attempted this proof by contradiction. Beginning with assuming to the contrary that each a and b are irrational but was not sure if I did it correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Assume $r,s \in\mathbb{Q}$.

a) Prove $\frac{r}{s}\in\mathbb{Q}$

b) Prove $r-s \in\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Try a direct proof instead. Proof by contradiction is not ideal here.

Comment: Don't do a proof by contradiction.  Simply assign r and s to n/m and k/l as integers and actually divide and subtract them and see what you get.

Comment: Nitpick.  if s = 0 then r/s is not rational.

Comment: A direct proof is very simple, so a proof by contradiction is a bad idea. But more important, no, you did not set up the proof by contradiction correctly! A proof by contradiction would begin by assuming $a$ and $b$ are _rational_ and $a+b$ is irrational. (Because assuming exactly _that_ is the same as assuming that it's not true that the sum of any two rationals is rational.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x\in\mathbb Q\iff \exists a,b\in\mathbb Z: b\ne0,\  x=\frac ab$

Let $r=\frac pq$,$s=\frac tu$, where $p,q,t,u\in\mathbb Z$ and $u,q\ne0$. Then,

If $s=0$, $\frac rs$ is not defined. Assuming, $s\ne0$,thus, $t\ne0$. $\frac rs=\frac {pu}{qt}$, where $pu,qt\in\mathbb Z$, as $t,q\ne0$; $qt\ne0$. Thus, $\frac rs\in\mathbb Q$.

$r-s=\frac {pu-tq}{qu}$, where $pu-tq,qu\in\mathbb Z$, and $qu\ne$ as $q,n\ne0$. Thus, $r-s\in\mathbb Q$